# Perl, how to fetch data from urls in parallel?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fetch

I need to fetch some data from many web data providers, who do not expose any service, so I have to write something like this, using for example WWW::Mechanize:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
@urls = ('http://www.first.data.provider.com', 'http://www.second.data.provider.com', 'http://www.third.data.provider.com');
%results = {};
foreach my $url (@urls) {
 $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
 $mech->get($url);
 $mech->form_number(1);
 $mech->set_fields('user' => 'myuser', pass => 'mypass');
 $resp = $mech->submit();
 $results{$url} = parse($resp->content());
}
consume(%results);
```

Is there some (possibly simple ;-) way to fetch data to a common %results variable, *simultaneously*, i.e: in parallel, from *all* the providers?

Comment: LWP::Parallel::UserAgent was written for this purpose, but I rarely see it mentioned nowadays.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`threads` are to be avoided in Perl.  `use threads` is mostly for
emulating UNIX-style fork on Windows; beyond that, it's pointless.

(If you care, the implementation makes this fact very clear.  In perl,
the interpreter is a `PerlInterpreter` object.  The way `threads`
works is by making a bunch of threads, and then creating a brand-new
PerlInterpreter object in each thread.  Threads share absolutely
nothing, even less than child processes do; `fork` gets you
copy-on-write, but with `threads`, all the copying is done in Perl
space!  Slow!)

If you'd like to do many things concurrently in the same process, the
way to do that in Perl is with an event loop, like
[EV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?EV),
[Event](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Event), or
[POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE), or by using Coro.  (You can
also write your code in terms of the `AnyEvent` API, which will let
you use any event loop.  This is what I prefer.)  The difference
between the two is how you write your code.

[AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent) (and EV, Event,
POE, and so on) forces you to write your code in a callback-oriented
style.  Instead of control flowing from top to bottom, control is in a
continuation-passing style.  Functions don't return values, they call
other functions with their results.  This allows you to run many IO
operations in parallel -- when a given IO operation has yielded
results, your function to handle those results will be called.  When
another IO operation is complete, that function will be called.  And
so on.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to rewrite your
code.  So there's a module called `Coro` that gives Perl real
(user-space) threads that will let you write your code top-to-bottom,
but still be non-blocking.  (The disadvantage of this is that it
heavily modifies Perl's internals.  But it seems to work pretty well.)

So, since we don't want to rewrite
[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize)
tonight, we're going to use Coro.  Coro comes with a module called
[Coro::LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Coro%3a%3aLWP) that will make
all calls to [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) be
non-blocking.  It will block the current thread ("coroutine", in Coro
lingo), but it won't block any other threads.  That means you can make
a ton of requests all at once, and process the results as they become
available.  And Coro will scale better than your network connection;
each coroutine uses just a few k of memory, so it's easy to have tens
of thousands of them around.

With that in mind, let's see some code.  Here's a program that starts
three HTTP requests in parallel, and prints the length of each
response.  It's similar to what you're doing, minus the actual
processing; but you can just put your code in where we calculate the
length and it will work the same.

We'll start off with the usual Perl script boilerplate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then we'll load the Coro-specific modules:

```
use Coro;
use Coro::LWP;
use EV;
```

Coro uses an event loop behind the scenes; it will pick one for you if
you want, but we'll just specify EV explicitly.  It's the best event
loop.

Then we'll load the modules we need for our work, which is just:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
```

Now we're ready to write our program.  First, we need a list of URLs:

```
my @urls = (
    'http://www.google.com/',
    'http://www.jrock.us/',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/',
);
```

Then we need a function to spawn a thread and do our work.  To make a
new thread on Coro, you call `async` like `async { body; of the
thread; goes here }`.  This will create a thread, start it, and
continue with the rest of the program.

```
sub start_thread($) {
    my $url = shift;
    return async {
        say "Starting $url";
        my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
        $mech->get($url);
        printf "Done with $url, %d bytes\n", length $mech->content;
    };
}
```

So here's the meat of our program.  We just put our normal LWP program
inside async, and it will be magically non-blocking.  `get` blocks,
but the other coroutines will run while waiting for it to get the data
from the network.

Now we just need to start the threads:

```
start_thread $_ for @urls;
```

And finally, we want to start handling events:

```
EV::loop;
```

And that's it.  When you run this, you'll see some output like:

```
Starting http://www.google.com/
Starting http://www.jrock.us/
Starting http://stackoverflow.com/
Done with http://www.jrock.us/, 5456 bytes
Done with http://www.google.com/, 9802 bytes
Done with http://stackoverflow.com/, 194555 bytes
```

As you can see, the requests are made in parallel, and you didn't have
to resort to `threads`!

**Update**

You mentioned in your original post that you want to limit the number of HTTP requests that run in parallel.  One way to do that is with a semaphore, 
[Coro::Semaphore](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Coro%3a%3aSemaphore) in Coro.

A semaphore is like a counter.  When you want to use the resource that a semaphore protects, you "down" the semaphore.  This decrements the counter and continues running your program.  But if the counter is at zero when you try to down the semaphore, your thread/coroutine will go to sleep until it is non-zero.  When the count goes up again, your thread will wake up, down the semaphore, and continue.  Finally, when you're done using the resource that the semaphore protects, you "up" the semaphore and give other threads the chance to run.

This lets you control access to a shared resource, like "making HTTP requests".

All you need to do is create a semaphore that your HTTP request threads will share:

```
my $sem = Coro::Semaphore->new(5);
```

The 5 means "let us call 'down' 5 times before we block", or, in other words, "let there be 5 concurrent HTTP requests".

Before we add any code, let's talk about what can go wrong.  Something bad that could happen is a thread "down"-ing the semaphore, but never "up"-ing it when it's done.  Then nothing can ever use that resource, and your program will probably end up doing nothing.  There are lots of ways this could happen.  If you wrote some code like `$sem->down; do something; $sem->up`, you might feel safe, but what if "do something" throws an exception?  Then the semaphore will be left down, and that's bad.

Fortunately, Perl makes it easy to have scope [Guard](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Guard) objects, that will automatically run code when the variable holding the object goes out of scope.  We can make the code be `$sem->up`, and then we'll never have to worry about holding a resource when we don't intend to.

Coro::Semaphore integrates the concept of guards, meaning you can say `my $guard = $sem->guard`, and that will automatically down the semaphore and up it when control flows away from the scope where you called `guard`.

With that in mind, all we have to do to limit the number of parallel requests is `guard` the semaphore at the top of our HTTP-using coroutines:

```
async {
    say "Waiting for semaphore";
    my $guard = $sem->guard;
    say "Starting";
    ...;
    return result;
}
```

Addressing the comments:

If you don't want your program to live forever, there are a few options.  One is to run the event loop in another thread, and then `join` on each worker thread.  This lets you pass results from the thread to the main program, too:

```
async { EV::loop };

# start all threads
my @running = map { start_thread $_ } @urls;

# wait for each one to return
my @results = map { $_->join } @running;

for my $result (@results) {
    say $result->[0], ': ', $result->[1];
}
```

Your threads can return results like:

```
sub start_thread($) {
    return async {
        ...;
        return [$url, length $mech->content];
    }
}
```

This is one way to collect all your results in a data structure. If you don't want to return things, remember that all the coroutines share state.  So you can put:

```
my %results;
```

at the top of your program, and have each coroutine update the results:

```
async {
    ...;
    $results{$url} = 'whatever';
};
```

When all the coroutines are done running, your hash will be filled with the results.  You'll have to `join` each coroutine to know when the answer is ready, though.

Finally, if you are doing this as part of a web service, you should use a coroutine-aware web server like [Corona](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Corona).  This will run each HTTP request in a coroutine, allowing you to *handle* multiple HTTP requests in parallel, in addition to being able to *send* HTTP requests in parallel.  This will make very good use of memory, CPU, and network resources, and will be pretty easy to maintain!

(You can basically cut-n-paste our program from above into the coroutine that handles the HTTP request; it's fine to create new coroutines and `join` inside a coroutine.)

Comment: Hi, jrockway, thanks for your long answer (you did copy-and-paste one of your prevoius stories, didn't you? ;-). However I find it very useful, I'm going to implement this solution, threads in fact are giving me many problems (not least the fact you "cannot share nested references using threads::shared", so you can't share a hash reference... :-().

Comment: I did just implement your solution. I have a couple of issues, probably due to my scarce familiarity with IPC, sorry... One: EV::loop does never end, how do I exit from my program (it's intended to be a web service...)? Two: (probably this is solved with the same answer to One...): how do I consume collected data at once (ie: in one single hash)?

Comment: I also added a blurb about semaphores

Comment: thanks, I did completely miss the join part... I'm up and running, now... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [ParallelUserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ParallelUserAgent/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer using threads directly, to keep using WWW::Mechanize, which is very handy, in my use case...

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could create threads to do it--specifically see `perldoc perlthrtut` and [Thread::Queue](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Queues%3a-Passing-Data-Around).  So, it might look something like this.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;
my @urls=(#whatever
);
my %results :shared;
my $queue=Thread::Queue->new();
foreach(@urls)
{
   $queue->enqueue($_);
}

my @threads=();
my $num_threads=16; #Or whatever...a pre-specified number of threads.

foreach(1..$num_threads)
{
    push @threads,threads->create(\&mechanize);
}

foreach(@threads)
{
   $queue->enqueue(undef);
}

foreach(@threads)
{
   $_->join();
}

consume(\%results);

sub mechanize
{
    while(my $url=$queue->dequeue)
    {
        my $mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();
        $mech->get($url);
        $mech->form_number(1);
        $mech->set_fields('user' => 'myuser', pass => 'mypass');
        $resp = $mech->submit();
        $results{$url} = parse($resp->content());
    }
}
```

Note that since you're storing your results in a hash (instead of writing stuff to a file), you shouldn't need any kind of locking **unless** there's a danger of overwriting values.  In which case, you'll want to lock `%results` by replacing

`$results{$url} = parse($resp->content());`

with

```
{
    lock(%results);
    $results{$url} = parse($resp->content());
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try out your solution now (I'm new to IPC, sorry... ;-). I suppose there is no danger of overwriting values, since %results is indexed by unique valued (urls are all unique, of course...).

Comment: No worries, I still consider myself new to programming in general.  :)  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I should also add that since you're passing values from `@urls` right into the queue, you should verify that all of them are defined (probably something like `@urls=grep{defined($_)}@urls`) before popping them in the queue.  Otherwise, if a thread hits an `undef` element in the queue, it exits out of the `while` loop and--since there's nothing else in `&mechanize` except the while loop--shuts down.

Comment: Of course, thanks. My @urls come from config values, so I am quite safe because they are checked already... I just finished to write down a full working piece of code based on your example, and it works like a charm... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the loop in your code

foreach(@threads)
{
   $queue->enqueue(undef);
}

Is it right? What's it's use? I can't find any documentation about enqueing undef's...

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  As for your question, the `while(my $line=$queue->dequeue)` loop in `&mechanize` instructs the thread to pop the next item off of `$queue`, and wait if there is nothing in `$queue`.  The only way that the loop terminates on its own is if it picks up an element off of `$queue` that is undefined (this is really because `while(my $line=$queue->dequeue)` is really shorthand for `while(defined(my $line=$queue->dequeue))`).  So, without enqueueing `undef`s, the threads would sit there forever, constantly waiting for more URLs to process.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI, whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel::Iterator -- saw a very good presentation about it last week, and one of the examples was parallel retrieval of URLs -- it's also covered in the pod example. It's simpler than using threads manually (although it uses fork underneath).

As far as I can tell, you'd still be able to use `WWW::Mechanize`, but avoid messing about with memory sharing between threads. It's a higher-level model for this task, and might be a little simpler, leaving the main logic of @Jack Maney's mechanize routine intact.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try the Coro solution, beforehand: it looks cleaner to me, at first sight.

Comment: Good luck. Personally, I have a preference for approaches that lean on the OS where needed (that's why I don't like threads). AnyEvent also does language changes, but not in core Perl (which is a good thing) but it is a distinctive style. In a self-contained script, it'll be very neat, though.

Comment: Agree that Coro is the strangest way to solve this problem when you look behind the scenes.  The best solution is to rewrite Mech to be non-blocking, and then use an event loop directly.  But that's hard, and Coro, while evil, is also well maintained.  So I consider it a good solution for "part of my app is nonblocking, but I don't want to rewrite the rest".